# How to find all the matches in a table?

Tags: r, match

I know the function

```
match(x, dataset)
```

but that only shows the first position of the match found and I need to specify which column in the table in order to get the result. So if there's a table like this

```
   x1  x2   ...
1   3   1   ...
2   4   2   ...
3   1   1   ...
4   2   4   ...
```

how can I find the position of all the number 1s?
I want to get the row and column number separately. Like the result of the above example should be 1,3(row) and x1,x2(column).

Comment: Do you mean you want the row and column for every value of one? If so, `which(dataset == 1, arr.ind=TRUE)`, If not, can you show your expecte outcome please

Comment: I just add expected outcome, please help me.

Comment: Thanks for updating, but its still a little unclear to me. There are three ones in your data - do you want the row and column number for each of these? Did you try the code from my comment above - can you explain why is it not what you want, to help us move towards what you want. cheers

Comment: oh, sorry.. you are right, it shows all three. thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome ... If it solves your problem please feel free to write it up as an answer (and mark it as solved). cheers

Comment: thank you so much, this is my first question on stack overflow. sorry if it's kind of stupid. but it seems I can't answer and mark my own answer as solved because of some restrictions. Maybe you can answer it and I well mark it as the answer. thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dat == 1` will give you a matrix where positions equal 1 with `TRUE` otherwise `FALSE`.

Additionally, you can find the `row` and `column` positions of the elements that meet your condition (in this case, equal to one is`TRUE`), by using `which` and the `arr.ind` argument.

Your data

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
  "x1  x2   
1   3   1   
2   4   2   
3   1   1   
4   2   4 ")
```

Extract positions where your data equals one

```
which(dat==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
#   row col
# 3   3   1
# 1   1   2
# 3   3   2
```

Comment: If they want to find all the 1s in the data, they should probably use `dataset == 1` to produce the matrix

Comment: Ups, my typo. Thanks!

Comment: just edit the question. I want to get the row and column number separately. Like the result of the above example should be 1,3(row) and x1,x2(column). I would be really grateful if you can help.